# Upgrading the RAM of an Ideapad 310-14ikb to 20GB?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop

Someone wants some help upgrading their laptop's RAM and when I looked up the model on Lenovo's website, it says it can be upgraded up to 12GB. (It has a 4GB soldered RAM) however, Crucial says that it can support a maximum of 20GB (4GB + 16GB) https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-310-14ikb

So I'm conflicted, the person was asking my opinion and I don't want them to buy a 16GB RAM stick and end up not being able to use it in the end but at the same time they could really use the extra 8GB of RAM (from the 12GB supposed max that Lenovo claims.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem likely that this system CAN support 32 gigs of RAM.  The processor can (i5-7200U) can support it, I've never known Crucial to be wrong on their memory, and there are other sites (eg https://www.gadgetsnow.com/laptops/Lenovo-Ideapad-310-14IKB-80TU00DKIN-Laptop-Core-i5-7th-Gen8-GB1-TBWindows-10 ) which show it as supported.

Its worth pointing out that Kingston claim only 12 gigs, so the jury may still be  out. https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/model/97727/lenovo-ideapad-310-14ikb  Of-course it may simply be that they don't sell 16gig sticks compatible with this system.  It is likely that this is simply not a configuration tested or supported by Lenovo (and its not uncommon for systems to support more RAM then stated by the manufacturer)

That said, I don't think anyone can absolutely guarantee it will work in your machine unless they try it.  A possible solution is to buy them memory from the Crucial.com website and take advantage of their 100% compatibility Guarantee (https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/crucial-compatibility-guarantee) or purchase from someone that will take the memory back if its not compatible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll pass this along. Additionally, will there be issues with mismatched RAM sizes in terms of performance? Or does that only happen when they have differing speeds?

Comment: I'm not an expert on RAM speeds, but it is likely that memory speed would be similar to that of a single SODIM.  If you did get a matching 4 gig SODIM it could be faster - but on a 5 year old system this should not be a significant concern (And the same problem is true regardless of whether you expand by 8 or 16 gigs - assuming there is not currently a 4 gig SODIM in the expansion slot for a total of 8 gigs before upgrade)

Comment: Another possible reason for Lenovo only stating 12 GiB is that 16 GiB sticks weren't available *at the time* when the laptop was new, and they haven't updated their info since?  That would be a bit odd; 5 years isn't that long ago and I think 16G sticks were available.

Comment: @user9564371: On my Skylake desktop, which presumably has more or less identical memory controllers to a Kaby Lake mobile chip, IIRC my Asus motherboard manual mentions mismatched DIMMs.  At best you'll get dual-channel bandwidth for the first 8GiB of physical RAM, with the 4GiB stick interleaved 1:1 with the first 4G of the larger DIMM.  Then the rest of physical RAM will run at single-channel memory bandwidth.  The OS probably won't know this and won't try to keep "hotter" data in those pages.

Comment: @user9564371: Fortunately memory bandwidth isn't usually the main limiting factor for a lot of desktop workloads.  But it can be for number-crunching (scientific computing) or graphics, especially integrated graphics.  (One might hope that an iGPU might be aware of which part of RAM was faster and use that.)  Of course, lots of things benefit from having more RAM even if it's not as high bandwidth so it's potentially a worthwhile tradeoff if the laptop's still in good condition; the memory clock should be high enough on Kaby Lake that single-channel isn't terrible.

Comment: @user9564371: A new stick of RAM rated for higher speeds than the built-in RAM should be able to match its frequency and timings, so it shouldn't ever be worse than running purely from a single channel.